# Stop an image/gif repeating

Tags: html, css, forum, repeat

I need help with a problem which I am having while editing ranks/groups on my forum.

Here is a screenshot of it currently:
[image: My Issue]

As you can see, the sparkle gif has continued all the way to the left.
I would  like it to end at the end of the username.

Current CSS (additional.css):

```
.admin{
    color:#FF0000;
    font-weight:bold;
    background:url(url for my redstar.png) no-repeat,url('url for my sparkle gif');
    padding-left:18px
}
```

Current HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/additional.css" />
    <div class="admin">USERNAME HERE</div>
</link>
```

Comment: then wrap the username in a span and put the background on the span. divs by default will go the full width of the parent container.

Comment: you should invest some time into learning correct html/css first. even if we help you now, you have some mistakes that you will continue to make without proper knowledge

Comment: @Abdul Ahmad Yep that span tag is the one, thank you everyone!

Answer (score -1):

As you are giving two backgrounds at a time which is possible with CSS3, you have to mention background-repeat separately

```
.admin{
     color:#FF0000;
     font-weight:bold;
     background:url(url for my redstar.png), 
     url('url for my sparkle gif');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     padding-left:18px;
}
```

And Yes! You need to learn HTML/CSS more :)

Comment: this doesn't fit the background to the length of the username.

Comment: I guess `background-size: cover;` might help with that.